# Nginx downloading files

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location, php-5.4

I have a server (nginx/1.6.0 PHP 5.5.14) with these settings that works correctly. The problem is when I use the `location ^~ /sys/` When I try to access the sys folder it downloads the index.  If I remove `location ^~ / sys /` back to working normally. he error only happens with php files. html files works normally. Where is the error?

```
server {
    server_name  site.com;
    root /home/www/site.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / { 
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php; 
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/data/php5514/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ^~ /sys/ {
    }
}
```

I'm using a script and need to do this setup in nginx to protect a folder from unauthorized access.

```
location ^~ /FOLDER/ {
    if ($cookie_amember_nr !~* [a-zA-Z0-9]+) { #not authorized
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://EXAMPLE.COM/AMEMBER/protect/new-rewrite?f=FOLDERID&url=$request_uri?$args redirect;
    }
    set $file $document_root/AMEMBER/data/new-rewrite/$cookie_amember_nr-FOLDERID;
    if (!-f $file) { #have not access
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://EXAMPLE.COM/AMEMBER/no-access/folder/id/FOLDERID?url=$request_uri?$args redirect;
    }    
    #everything is ok
}
```

But this problem with `location ^ ~` does not work.

Comment: Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explain more detailed what you actually expect.

Assuming you want to serve php content at /sys/, you must also put the fastcgi_pass block in this location context like so:

```
location ^~ /sys/ {
     fastcgi_pass unix:/data/php5514/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
     include fastcgi_params;
}
```

If that's what you want, you'd propably want to use [upstream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html):

```
upstream php { server unix:/data/php5514/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; }
```

and reference it as

```
location ^~ /sys/ {
     fastcgi_pass http://php;
}
```

on both/all location blocks serving php.

Remember, exact location matches win over less exact/almost matches. Maybe your GET request to /sys/something.php does not get matched by the php-location block, but by the /sys-location block. 
What's the use of the sys-location block anyway, if you don't put something in there like a different root?

Comment: What I expect from the / sys / folder is that when trying to access the files and subfolders it does not return with a file download.

Comment: what files? php?